# Oracle/Apex: adding an internal user to a table?

Tags: sql, database, oracle-apex

I am trying to add an internal APEX user to a user_Table that I created and I am unsure how to do this. 
Using this video provided by our university: http://youtu.be/69rVjyepf5g

I was wondering how I would go about adding this new user to the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE user_table (
userId NUMBER NOT NULL, 
userName VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL, 
emailAddress     VARCHAR2(150) NOT NULL, 
password VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(userId)
);
```

I know the video shows lines such as:

```
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Current user is ' || currentUser);
```

to display what user is currently in use in the system.

I am looking for a way to add a selected interal user to my user table for use in my application.

Any help would be much appreciated, thank you.

Comment: The video you linked is only about adding an apex user and then shows how to get the logged in user's name. What is the relation between the video and retrieving the username and having an own table? What do you mean by " I can't figure out how this is added to my table": what is "this" ? Your question seems to be "how can I create and manage users in my own table and how can I authenticate with them" - but is it?

Comment: Sorry - I'll try to clarify. Our lecturer provided us with this video to show us how to add internal users with the intention that we would then use these users  as users for our coursework piece but no information was provided as to how to do this. Does that make more sense?

Comment: That gives more background, though its still unclear why you are wanting to use your table "user_table"? Why would you want to store an apex-created user to this table? There isn't really a point to doing that, it's storing data twice. Or is that the point exactly?

Comment: To be honest, our coursework spec is very vague and our lecturer will not give us any more guidance. Maybe a better question would be - how do I link the users to other tables? (we have to create a facebook like application with friends, posts, responses and groups)

Comment: Well, decide on what course you want to go. If you want to use the apex workspace users, that is possible. They are in a table, have a UK,  can be queried and there is an authentication scheme for it. If you have your own table, you'll have to have management screens for it and have to set up an authentication. I mean, both ways work, but there is no point to mixing them up. And if the question is: how can i add an apex user to my own table after it is created, then that is not possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get this working by creating the user as an object:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE user_Object AS OBJECT(
userId NUMBER,
userName VARCHAR2(30),
emailAddress VARCHAR2(100),
MAP MEMBER FUNCTION get_userId RETURN NUMBER ) NOT FINAL;
```

Then creating a table referencing that object:

```
CREATE TABLE user_table OF user_Object;
```

Then I inserted the data into the table

```
INSERT INTO user_table VALUES('1','USER1','user@email.com');
```

And created a user with the name 'USER' as per the original linked video!

I then use the following query to select the friends that are saved under that specific user

```
ELECT DISTINCT B.userfriend.userName FROM friends_table B 
WHERE  B.friendId = (select C.userId FROM user_table C WHERE C.userName =(SELECT V('APP_USER') FROM DUAL));
```